# Pandas - write dataframe in fixed-width formatted lines to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Have a huge pandas dataframe (df) like this:

```
        id          date      a      b      c
0     0023  201110132120    -30    -45      7
1     0023  201110132130    -30     11   9111
2     0023  201110132140    -24     44    345
3     0023  201110132150    -19    223     11
4     0023  201110132200    -23  -3456  -1250
```

I need to write this dataframe to a file with special fixed-width for each field.
For this i used numpy, f.e.:

```
np.savetxt('out.txt', df.values, fmt='%+4s %+12s %+5s %+5s %+6s')
```

That work's fine. Only lost header in this case. Is there a workaround?

I tested it also with pandas to_string function:

```
df.to_string()
```

But it is so slow. Why? Are there other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to abuse `header` option in `savetxt`:

```
formats = '%+4s %+12s %+5s %+5s %+6s'

headers = [format(str(x),y.replace('%+','>')) 
              for x, y in zip(df.columns,formats.split())]

np.savetxt('out.txt', df.values, fmt=formats,
           header=' '.join(headers), comments='')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header='{:>4s} {:>12s} {:>5s} {:>5s} {:>6s}'.format('id','date','a','b','d')
np.savetxt('out.txt', df.values, fmt='%+4s %+12s %+5s %+5s %+6s', header=header)
```