# Python output fixed width format text file with special lines as SAS do

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, text, sas

I have the sample data as below:

```
# df
VAR1   SEQ    VAR2    VAR3       DATE    VAR4     VAR5    VAR6    VAR7
AAA      1     YYY      01   20000630      AL    11111    ABCD      PA
BBB      1     YYY      01   20100701      GA    12345    EDED      NY
BBB      2     YYY      01   20150815      GA    12345              NY
BBB      3     YYY      01   19950105      GA    12345    YTRU      NY
BBB      4     YYY      01   20000701      GA    12345    IIII      NY
BBB      5     YYY      01   20210701      GA    12345              NY
CCC      1     NNN      01   20210630      CA    33333    SSSS      NJ
CCC      2     NNN      01   20210629      CA    33333              NJ
```

In `SAS`, we can export fixed width format file as below:

```
BLANK_VAR1 = " "

%MACRO FRIST;
    PUT @  1  "00FIRST"
        @  8  VAR1       $CHAR5.
        @ 13  BLANK_VAR1 $CHAR2.
        @ 15  VAR2       $CHAR3.
    ;
%MEND FRIST;

%MACRO SECOND;
    PUT @  1  "00SECOND"
        @  9  VAR3       $CHAR2.
        @ 11  BLANK_VAR1 $CHAR2.
        @ 13  VAR4       $CHAR2.
        @ 15  VAR5       $CHAR5.
    ;
%MEND SECOND;

%MACRO THIRD(sequence);
    num = &sequence.;
    PUT @  1  num        Z2.0
        @  3  "THIRD"    $CHAR5.
        @  8  DATE       $CHAR8.
    ;
%MEND THIRD;

%MACRO FOURTH(sequence);
    num = &sequence.;
    PUT @  1  num        Z2.0
        @  3  "FOURTH"   $CHAR5.
        @  9  VAR6       $CHAR25.
        @ 34  BLANK_VAR1 $CHAR2.
        @ 36  VAR7       $CHAR2.
    ;
%MEND FOURTH;

filename outtmp "/home/folder/outfile_tmp";  

DATA _NULL_;                                                                    
   SET df;    
 
   BY VAR1 SEQ;                                                           
   FILE outtmp;  
                                                                
   IF FIRST.VAR1 THEN DO;
      %FRIST;
      %SECOND;
      REC_CNT = 0;                                                             
   END;                                                                       
   REC_CNT + 1;
   IF REC_CNT LE 3 THEN DO;
      %THIRD(REC_CNT);
      IF VAR6 NE ' ' THEN DO;
         %FOURTH(COUNTN);
      END;
   END;                                                         
RUN;


filename output "/home/folder/output"; 


%MACRO INREC;                                                                     
   PUT 001 RECIN $CHAR150.;
%MEND INREC;


%MACRO FILE_FIRST;
    DATE = TODAY();
    PUT @  1  "###FIRSTLINE###"
        @ 16  DATE       JULIAN5.
        @ 21  BLANK_VAR1 $CHAR2.
        @ 23  "###FIRSTLINEEND###"
    ;
%MEND FILE_FIRST;


%MACRO FILE_LAST;
    DATE = TODAY();
    PUT @  1  "###LASTLINE###"
        @ 15  DATE       JULIAN5.
        @ 20  BLANK_VAR1 $CHAR2.
        @ 22  "###LASTLINEEND###"
    ;
%MEND FILE_LAST;


DATA output;                                                                  
   INFILE outtmp truncover;                                                               
   INPUT                                                                       
      @ 001 RECIN $CHAR150.;                                                                         
RUN; 

DATA _NULL_;
   SET output  end=last;  
   file output  lrecl=256 ;
   IF _N_ = 1 THEN DO;
      %FILE_FIRST;
   END;

   %INREC;  
                                                                  
   IF last THEN DO;
      %FILE_LAST; 
   END;
RUN;
```

This is the output:
[image]

```
###FIRSTLINE###21182  ###LASTLINEEND###
00FIRSTAAA  YYY
00SECOND01  AL11111
01THIRD20000630
01FOURTHABCD                       PA
00FIRSTBBB  YYY
00SECOND01  GA12345
01THIRD20100701
01FOURTHEDED                       NY
02THIRD20150815
03THIRD19950105
03FOURTHYTRU                       NY
00FIRSTCCC  NNN
00SECOND01  CA33333
01THIRD20210630
01FOURTHSSSS                       NJ
###LASTLINE###21182  ###LASTLINEEND###
```

The **logic** for above program is:

1. There are four parts that needed to be output.
2. If there are multiple same `VAR1`, then only output `FIRST` and `SECOND` once.
3. Output `THIRD` part for `SEQ` is less than 3. If the `SEQ` is larger than 3, do not output. Ignore.
4. Output the `FOURTH` part following the third logic and also if `VAR6` is not missing.
5. Note: In `THIRD` and `FOURTH` part, the first two string should change from `01` to `03` depends on the records.

How can I replicate this format in `Python`?
I found that `np.savetxt()` with `fmt` argument might be a way [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64826735/7651845); however, the file should be the same order as original dataframe.

`pandas` has function `read_fwf()` to read fixed width format file; however, no `to_fwf()` function to export.

I have been stuck for several days, so any idea should be helpful!

Comment: I imagine you'd just make the full line one string, then write that?

Comment: @Joe First and Last line might be done by this but the middle part is difficult to do so if you have a large dataset.

Comment: To be clear, you just want your data exported fixed width or something else?  I can't tell from the output you posted?

Comment: @PeterChen I mean, it's difficult in SAS too, but ... it's basically what you are doing *even in SAS* - you are converting the records to strings (in a text file) and then reading them back in and writing them out again.  (It's probably much easier to do this in SAS than you're doing it, honest, but leaving that aside...) The bigger problem here honestly is just stating the rules you're following - it's not really clear what the rules are, beyond the program instructions of course.  You write First Second once, Third three times, and Fourth if it has a value in the first three rows?

Comment: @JonSG Fixed with format is what he's doing in SAS, at least.  But it's more like it's being split across a bunch of rows, something that's sort of like the old "card column" format but not exactly that either... I presume it must be something for a bank system, as nothing else would be so odd.

Comment: @Joe I add the output logic to explain! Thanks for letting me know it is unclear!

Comment: Why are you re-creating SEQ as REC_CNT? Does SEQ not number the observations per VAR1 group?

Comment: Why did you post a photograph of the desired text output?  Please post the actual text you want otherwise it will be hard for anyone to test their answers.  Your picture looks wrong.  The state code is not in column 36.

Comment: @Tom Modified and changed the output... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly a good way to do it, but maybe it gives you an idea how to do the logic.  I'm just writing to a list, you can then write the list out - but probably you should do it the way JonSG did in his (deleted) answer where you use a file writer instead.  There's probably a better approach using a data class, but that's not my expertise.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"h:\temp\df_text.csv")

outlist = []

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['SEQ']==1):
        tempstr = '00FIRST'+row.VAR1+'  '+row.VAR2
        outlist.append(tempstr)
        tempstr = '00SECOND'+str(row.VAR3)+'  '+str(row.VAR4)+str(row.VAR5)
        outlist.append(tempstr)
    if(row['SEQ'] <= 3):
        seqval ='0'+str(row.SEQ) if  row.SEQ < 10 else str(row.SEQ)
        tempstr = str(row['SEQ'])+'THIRD'+str(row.DATE)
        outlist.append(tempstr)
        if (row.VAR6 != '  '):
            tempstr = str(row['SEQ'])+'FOURTH'+row.VAR6+'  '+row.VAR7
            outlist.append(tempstr)
```

Comment: Your answer fulfill the logic but the only thing is each output width/length (it seems that you use space directly to do so, cool!).. I'm also finding his delete answer but it seems that there is no record to track for now

Comment: is it possible to set up tuple in the list and use that for `FIRST`, `SECOND`, `THIRD`, and `FOURTH` output?

Comment: The way I did it, no, that wouldn't help - not that I can see anyway?  I think the "best" way to do this is with a [dataclass](https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/) that has the output built into it as a method, honestly, but the above either with a list or with a file writer should accomplish what you want - maybe with a little more care about formatting, as Jon shows, using the `{: <4}` type formatters.

Comment: It seems that we cannot check the deleted answer that @JonSG posted...