# Export pandas dataframe to .txt file without a delimeter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, txt

I am trying to export my pandas dataframe to .txt file without a delimiter in .txt file.

Example dataframe:

[image]

I want to export this dataframe as fixed format text file.

1. 4 chars always reserved for id. In our case 1 in the dataframe will look '1   ' in our txt file
2. 16 chars always reserved for name

The output must look like this
ID starts at 1st position and name must start at 5th position always

[image]

I am writing the below code but it still uses the delimeter

```
df.to_csv(r'path to txt file/test.txt',
          sep = " ",
          header=None,
          index = False,
          quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
          escapechar=" ")
```

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. To convert a dataframe to fixed width formatted .txt file, one must use the np.savetxt() function.

```
np.savetxt(r'path to txt file/test.txt', df.values, fmt='%-4s%-12s',encoding='UTF-8')
```

The above piece of code helps you convert to .txt file without a delimiter between two columns.

I get 4 chars always assigned to ID. '-' indicates that it is left justified. Similarly, 12 chars always assigned to Name column starting from 5th position

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following configuration:

```
sep ='\t'
```

This should create a tab separated file.

Edited:

If what you want is a fixed width format then you should convert the dataframe to a numpy array and use the following solution: [pandas-write-dataframe-in-fixed-width-formatted-lines-to-a-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64826735/pandas-write-dataframe-in-fixed-width-formatted-lines-to-a-file)